# mkdir: cannot create directory `foldername': Too many links

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu. When I tried to create a new directory under a folder with more than 30,000 subfolders, it displayed following error message:

mkdir: cannot create directory `foldername': Too many links

How can I raise the limit of subfolders number in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a different filesystem than ext3.  There's a hard limit built into ext[23].  Or, consider bucketing your directories into a multi-level hashed structure, to reduce the number of directories you need to store at a particular "layer".